# Form the biggest squaring number

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

You are going to start from any number with distinct digits lower than four digits (such as $a$, $ab$, $abc$) and you will apply the rule below:

- Take the square any number you want in the number (you may take the square the number itself too). (such as $1(02)$ -> $14$, or $12(3)$ -> $129$ or $(13)$ -> $169$)
- Every number you found has to have distinct digits. (Fail example: $(12)3$-> $1443$ X)
- You may apply this as many times as you want. ($(13)$ -> $169$ then $(16)9$->$2569$)

> What is the biggest final number you can have?

Comment: Biggest final number? or biggest starting number?

Comment: is there a restriction about how many digits the number which we square can have? like, if I get a number like 1023 as an interim result (even though 1023 itself is not possible), am I allowed to square it all to get to 1046529?

Comment: @elias "you may take the square the number itself too". written on the first rule. no restriction.

Comment: $1(69) -> 14761$. Isn't this a violation of the previous rule?

Comment: @WaisKamal ops true :) fixed it.

Comment: @Oray I removed the tag "logicial deduction" as a formal deduction seems impossible to me and indeed you have accepted an answer that used guesses / brute force. If I did wrong, feel free to revert (in that case I would very much like to read such a formal answer). Nice puzzle BTW!

Comment: @xhienne i do not believe this is straight forward brute force, requires some logic deducion too to come up with a good code, but thats fine without logic deduction tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

I've found

> **9857240136** to be maximal (confirmed with programming).

Many possible ways to reach it, here is one starting with...

> (4)2 -> 16(2) -> 1(6)4 -> 1(3)64 -> (1964) -> 3857(2)96 -> 3857(496) -> (3)85724016 -> 98572401(6) -> 9857240136

**Previous attempt:**

My new record is:

> **9810362574**

which can be reached via

> (5)74 -> (25)74 -> (625)74 -> 3(9)062574 -> (3)81062574 -> 9810(6)2574 -> 9810362574

**First attempt:**

Not proven to be maximal at all, but I managed to reach

> 10 digits with **4817093625**

The steps are:

> (705) -> 4(9)7025 -> 48170(25) -> 48170(6)25 -> 48170(3)625 -> 481709(6)25 -> 4817093625